# Divine impassibility + divine simplicity = strong impassibility?

Tags: theology, action, divine-simplicity

(In theory, this is a denomination- or even religion-neutral question about the concept of a divine being. We take properties (like omniscience or having avatars) or hyperproperties (like aseity or simplicity) and "axiomatize" them, then combine these "axioms" to see where things go "formally" or "rigorously.")

The [weak/strong impassibility distinction goes as follows:](https://geometrictheology.wordpress.com/2020/05/28/impassibility-redux/)

- A being is weakly impassible if this being is not a patient of any *other* agent.
- A being is strongly impassible if this being is not a patient of any agent *at all*, not even itself.

**Question:** can we apply a principle of divine simplicity to this pair of alternatives and say that if God was an agent unto all others but a patient of Itself, this would introduce a metaphysical plurality into the divine nature such as is contraindicated by divine simplicity? So that generic impassibility + metaphysical simplicity = strong impassibility, ultimately? Or is the agent/patient distinction more a relational one such that "being of patient of Itself" is a relation between Itself and Its action (upon Itself), so that there is no violation of internal simplicity?

Comment: Your definitions are rather odd. The usual ["passibility"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impassibility) is God's ability to have passions (experience emotions) and suffer, which "patient of an agent" does not exactly convey. Your link does give an argument for impassibility from simplicity/immutability (emotions are changes and God does not change), and is implies can. So yes, we can argue from Divine simplicity to this effect. Unless, of course, one shifts idioms in some way and applies passibility to God's incarnated human nature or to some relational construct, as you suggest.

Comment: Impassibility is nothing but the inability to become passive or get past by whereby a patient of another agent could be said to possess one of those passive abilities induced by the said agent. Therefore passibility/impassibility don't apply to cases for patient of itself. Also note the subtlety that any human's passive state must *not* be constant otherwise it's really a petrified state, thus for divine simplicity's sake, weak impassibility could mean God's being a patient of any other agent is very different from human's since there's no unknown fear or surprises of those for God,

Comment: and strong impassibility could mean unlike human God's passion is absolutely constant but not without emotion at all. So in either case God could still have emotion of impassibility consistently and there's really no mutual exclusivity of weak and strong impassibility within divine simplicity...

Comment: I'm not sure that after assuming an omniscient omnipotent creator we can still claim religion-neutrality :) Besides, even though this model's appeal is indeed in its simplicity, on a closer examination it quickly leads to paradoxes. Maybe the idea of divine simplicity originally meant something different, something along the lines of 2 Corinthians 11:3? Or what Einstein allegedly said --  "If you can't explain it to a ten-year-old..."